# Cannot get basic localization to work with ASP.NET 5

Tags: localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying localize my ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 (RC1) project. Unfortunately the official documentation is still missing so I based my experiments mainly on [this](http://www.vodovnik.com/2015/09/20/localization-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/) and [this](http://damienbod.com/2015/10/21/asp-net-5-mvc-6-localization/) blog posts.

Here is what I did: In `Configure` (Startup.cs) I have

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
    {
        new CustomRequestCultureProvider(httpContext => Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("de-CH"))),
        new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider()
    }
}, new RequestCulture("en-US"));
```

Note that the first entry in my `RequestCultureProviders` list always returns the `de-CH` culture. So I would expect that the `AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider` as well as the default `RequestCulture` (`en-US`) have no influence.

However when I look at

```
HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().RequestCulture.Culture.Name;
```

in some controller action, its value is `en-US` and not the expected `de-CH`.

I then tried to change the default `RequestCulture` in `Configure` from `en-US` to `de-DE` and now when I look at

```
HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().RequestCulture.Culture.Name;
```

in my controller action, it has the value `de-DE`.

**So the question is**: Why does ASP.NET fall back to the default culture instead of using the culture `de-CH` provided by my `CustomRequestCultureProvider`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you must also include "de-CH" in the list of supported cultures.  For example, the following returns "de-CH" as the culture, but if I comment out the lines setting `SupportedCultures`, it displays "en-US".  In an MVC application, you might also have to set `SupportedUICultures`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("de-CH")
        },
        RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
        {
            new CustomRequestCultureProvider(httpContext => Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("de-CH"))),
            new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider()
        }
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions, new RequestCulture("en-US"));

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        var envName = context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().RequestCulture.Culture.Name;

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World! " + envName);
    });
}
```

The description for the `SupportedCultures` property says a value of `null` indicates all cultures are supported and that `null` is the default, but testing indicates otherwise, as does the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Localization/RequestLocalizationOptions.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// The cultures supported by the application. The <see cref="RequestLocalizationMiddleware"/> will only set
/// the current request culture to an entry in this list.
/// Defaults to <see cref="CultureInfo.CurrentCulture"/>.
/// </summary>
public IList<CultureInfo> SupportedCultures { get; set; } = new List<CultureInfo> { CultureInfo.CurrentCulture };
```